# Mostrar resultados de una consulta a una BBDD

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Buenas, tengo este código PHP, con una base de datos con la tabla "imagenes" y con los campos: "id", "categoria" y "url". Cuando intento seleccionar todas las imágenes de una categoría, sólo me devuelve la primera imagen de esa categoría acompañada de la siguiente notificación:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\11\index.php on line 31

Mi código PHP es el siguiente:

```
            $imagen_buscar = "Habitaciones";

            require_once("conexion-bd.php");

            try{

                $sql_buscar = $mysqli->stmt_init();
                $sql_buscar->prepare("SELECT url FROM imagenes WHERE categoria=?");
                $sql_buscar->bind_param("s", $imagen_buscar);
                $sql_buscar->execute();

                $resultado = $sql_buscar->get_result();
                //$fila = $resultado->fetch_row();
                $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

                print_r($fila);

                for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){



                    print_r("<img src='/proyectos/11/galeria/".$fila[$i]."' alt='Imagen buscada' width='50%' />");

                }

                unset($mysqli);

            }catch (Exception $mysqli_ex3){

                die("Se produjo el siguiente error: " . "<br/>" . $mysqli_ex3->getMessage() . "<br/>" . $mysqli_ex3->getCode() .  "<br/>");
            }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error te sale porque intentas acceder en el `for` a un array por clave/índice, la cual no existe.

Intenta con un `foreach`:

```
foreach( $fila as $url ) {

    echo "<img src='/proyectos/11/galeria/{$url}' alt='Imagen buscada' width='50%' />";
}
```

**Edit:**

En primer lugar hemos quitado el fallo del `Notice: Undefined offset: ...`, respondiendo ahora a tu comentario:

Para que funcione tu código en la totalidad, es decir quitando algunos fallos, ej. mezcla de la api y obtener el resultado, quedaría tú código de la siguiente forma:

```
....

$sql_buscar = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$sql_buscar->prepare( "SELECT url FROM imagenes WHERE categoria=?" );
$sql_buscar->bind_param( "s", $imagen_buscar );
$sql_buscar->execute();

$resultado = $sql_buscar->get_result();

while ( $fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {

  echo "<img src='/proyectos/11/galeria/{$fila['url']}' alt='Imagen buscada' width='50%' />";
}

...
```

Comment: Ahora me devuelve la primera imagen repetida dos veces. (Dentro de la categoría habitaciones sólo tengo dos imágenes).

Comment: @Jopimar - ya te he corregido tu código completo... saludos